# Django. How to remove a field from objects in the database?

Tags: python, django, django-models

First, field  `division` had choices with list of available divisions with  `default='No'` .
Then it ceased to be necessary, i tried just delete field from model, but get **django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (division) specified for Team**. Then i remove choice, default and set `division='None'` for all objects. I thought if the value is null (None) then the field can be safely removed, but got the same **FieldError: Unknown field(s) specified** again.

> How can I remove a field from a model, If the database already contains objects with specified field?

#### models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField("Logo", upload_to="img/teams",default="img/team.jpg")
    city = models.CharField("City",max_length=30, default="Moscow")
    division = models.CharField("Division", max_length=50, null=True)
    url = models.SlugField(
        max_length=30,
        unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried just delete field from model, but get `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (division) specified for Team`.

That `FieldError` is likely because you use `Team` in a `ModelForm`, `ModelAdmin`, `ModelSerializer`, or something else where **you specified that field**. For example a `ModelForm` with:

```
class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        #       reference to division ↓
        fields = ['name', 'city', 'division']
```

You thus should look at the *traceback* and find out what form, etc. is referencing to that field and update all the referencing items accordingly.

After doing that you can make a migration where `division` will be removed from the model.